# How to replace paired tokens with possible newlines inside?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, tr

Suppose I have a file, `test.txt`, containing:

```
$foobar$

$
foobar
$

$
foobar$

$foobar
$

$
foo
bar
$

$
foo
bar$

$foo
bar
$
```

I'd like each pair `$...$` to be replaced by `\(...\)`, the `...` possibly containing new lines. **Edit:** More precisely, I expect the following replacement:

```
\(foobar\)

\(
foobar
\)

\(
foobar\)

\(foobar
\)

\(
foo
bar
\)

\(
foo
bar\)

\(foo
bar
\)
```

The following `sed` instruction:

```
sed -e 's/\$\([^]]*\)\$/\\(\1\\)/g' test.txt
```

does the job only if there isn't any new line.

Another possibility is to make use of two passes:

1. the 1st one replacing one `$` out of two by `\(`
2. the 2nd one replacing all the remaining `$` by `\)`

but I don't know how to tell “one out of two”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner and the [flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
perl -pe 's/\$/\\(/ .. s/\$/\\)/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using gnu-awk:

```
awk -v RS='\\$[^$]*\\$' 'RT{sub(/\$/, "\\(", RT); sub(/\$/, "\\)\n", RT); print RT}' file
\(foobar\)

\(
foobar
\)

\(
foobar\)

\(foobar
\)

\(
foo
bar
\)

\(
foo
bar\)

\(foo
bar
\)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '{ while(/\$/) sub("\\$", ++c%2 ? "\\(" : "\\)" ) }1'  file
```